# I would like to regroup records thats have a logical suit together

Tags: java, groovy, hashmap

Hi so i'm trying to make Something like this :

```
id:1  First: -9999 Last: -9999 group: B 
id:2  First: -9999 Last: -9999 group: B 
id:3  First: 1 Last: 2 group: 0 
id:4  First: 2 Last: 3 group: 0 
id:5  First: 3 Last: 4 group: 0 
id:6  First: 6 Last: 7 group: 1 
id:7  First: 7 Last: 8 group: 1 
id:8  First: 8 Last: 9 group: 1
id:9  First: 9 Last: 10 group: 1
id:10  First: 99 Last: 100 group: 2 
id:11  First: 100 Last: 101 group: 2
id:12  First: 101 Last: 102 group: 2 
id:13  First: 201 Last: 200 group: 3
```

unfortunately for the moment i get this :

```
id:1  First: -9999 Last: -9999 group: B 
id:2  First: -9999 Last: -9999 group: B 
id:3  First: 1 Last: 2 group: 0 
id:4  First: 2 Last: 3 group: 1 
id:5  First: 3 Last: 4 group: 1 
id:6  First: 6 Last: 7 group: 2 
id:7  First: 7 Last: 8 group: 3 
id:8  First: 8 Last: 9 group: 3 
id:9  First: -9998 Last: -9998 group: B 
id:10  First: 99 Last: 100 group: 4 
id:11  First: 100 Last: 101 group: 5 
id:12  First: 101 Last: 102 group: 5 
id:13  First: 201 Last: 200 group: null
```

If anyone can help me with this , it will be very appreciate

```
data= [[OUT_FID_R2:-9999, OBJECTID_R2:1, IN_FID_R2:-9999], [OUT_FID_R2:-9999, OBJECTID_R2:2, IN_FID_R2:-9999], [OUT_FID_R2:2,OBJECTID_R2:3, IN_FID_R2:1], [OUT_FID_R2:3, OBJECTID_R2:4, IN_FID_R2:2], [OUT_FID_R2:4, OBJECTID_R2:5, IN_FID_R2:3], [OUT_FID_R2:7, OBJECTID_R2:6, IN_FID_R2:6], [OUT_FID_R2:8, OBJECTID_R2:7, IN_FID_R2:7], [OUT_FID_R2:9, OBJECTID_R2:8, IN_FID_R2:8],[OUT_FID_R2:-9998, OBJECTID_R2:9, IN_FID_R2:-9998],[OUT_FID_R2:100, OBJECTID_R2:10, IN_FID_R2:99], [OUT_FID_R2:101, OBJECTID_R2:11, IN_FID_R2:100], [OUT_FID_R2:102, OBJECTID_R2:12, IN_FID_R2:101], [OUT_FID_R2:200, OBJECTID_R2:13, IN_FID_R2:201]]  

  
data=data.unique()
    int cle=0
    for (int x=0; x<data.size();x++) {
        for (int j=0; j<data.size();j++){
            if(data[x]['IN_FID_R2']!= data[x]['OUT_FID_R2']){
                if(data[x]['OUT_FID_R2']==data[j]['IN_FID_R2']){
                    data[x].put('new_grp',cle)
                    data[j].put('new_grp',cle)
                    cle++
                }
            }     
            else{
                data[x].put('new_grp','B')
                }
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<data.size();i++){
        printf("id:%s  First: %s Last: %s group: %s \n",data[i]['OBJECTID_R2'],data[i]['IN_FID_R2'], data[i]['OUT_FID_R2'],data[i]['new_grp'])
    }
```

So for the moment after my first condition is found the group start at 0 but the one after start at 1  and it should keep the group as 0 since the last(id:3) and first(id:4) are the same and it seem that the group happen for 2 records only.

Comment: Please provide data; and it would _really_ help if you could point out the problems of your current result vs. the expected one, so others don't have to use diff or their stereo vision skills to find them.

Comment: Great im on it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your solution and you were on a good track. The only correction will be in your assignation of a new value once the sequential range is found. Here my answer :

```
int cle =0
for (int x=0; x<data.size();x++) {
    for (int j=0; j<data.size();j++){
        if(data[x]['IN_FID_R2']!= data[x]['OUT_FID_R2']){
            if(data[x]['OUT_FID_R2']==data[j]['IN_FID_R2']){

                if (data[x]['new_grp'] ==null && data[x]['new_grp'] ==null ){
                    
                    data[x].put('new_grp',[cle])
                    data[j].put('new_grp',[cle])

                    
                }else if (data[x]['new_grp'] ==null || data[j]['new_grp'] ==null ){

                    respond= data[x]['new_grp']+data[j]['new_grp']
                    
                    data[x].put('new_grp',respond.findAll{it != null})
                    
                    data[j].put('new_grp',respond.findAll{it != null})      

                }
                     
                cle++
            }
        }     
        else{
            data[x].put('new_grp','B')
            }
    }

}
```

The expected result will be :

```
id:1  First: -9999 Last: -9999 group: B 
id:2  First: -9999 Last: -9999 group: B 
id:3  First: 1 Last: 2 group: [0] 
id:4  First: 2 Last: 3 group: [0] 
id:5  First: 3 Last: 4 group: [0] 
id:6  First: 6 Last: 7 group: [2] 
id:7  First: 7 Last: 8 group: [2] 
id:8  First: 8 Last: 9 group: [2] 
id:9  First: -9998 Last: -9998 group: B 
id:10  First: 99 Last: 100 group: [4] 
id:11  First: 100 Last: 101 group: [4] 
id:12  First: 101 Last: 102 group: [4] 
id:13  First: 102 Last: 200 group: [4]
```